# Load a dataframe from a single json object

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following json object:

```
{
    "Name": "David",
    "Gender": "M",
    "Date": "2014-01-01",
    "Address": {
        "Street": "429 Ford",
        "City": "Oxford",
        "State": "DE",
        "Zip": 1009
    }
}
```

How would I load this into a pandas dataframe so that it orients itself as:

```
name     gender        date          address
David    M             20140-01-01   {...}
```

What I'm trying now is:

```
pd.read_json(file)
```

But it orients it as four records instead of one.

Comment: try `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file)`, given you convert your `file` to `dict type`

Comment: @meW no I've just copied and pasted the file data above. It never gets into a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read it as a Series and then (*optionally*) convert to a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(file, typ='series')).T
df.shape
#(1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON file is composed of 1 JSON object per line (not an array, not a pretty printed JSON object)

then you can use:

`df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)`

and it will do what you want

if file contains:

```
{"Name": "David","Gender": "M","Date": "2014-01-01","Address": {"Street": "429 Ford","City": "Oxford","State": "DE","Zip": 1009}}
```

on 1 line, then you get:

[image]

If you use

`df = pd.read_json(file, orient='records')`

you can load as 1 key per column, but the sub-keys will be split up into multiple rows.

[image]